# Number of subsets intersecting certain sets

Tags: combinatorics

I've puzzling this for a while, and I'm starting to doubt that there is a reasonable-looking closed form; and if you could give me some pointers towards which sorts of techniques I might want to look into, I'd like that.

Let $V_1$...$V_n$ be finite (and possibly intersecting) sets, and let $U$ be their union. I want to compute the number of subsets $W$ of $U$ which intersect all sets $V_i$. How can I write this nicely in terms of the sets $V_i$ (and of their intersections and so on, of course...)?

If I knew that the $V_i$ were pairwise disjoint, the solution would be very simple: for every $V_i$ I'd have $2^{|V_i|} - 1$ possible choices for $W \cap V_i$ (gotta remove the empty one), and thus the number of subsets of V would be simply $(2^{|V_1|} - 1)(2^{|V_2|}  - 1) ... (2^{|V_n|} - 1)$.

The general case, however, has resisted all my attempts so far. I attempted to write a formula that explicitly enumerated all partitions of $\{V_1...V_n\}$, and for any such partition $\mathcal P$ computed the number of sets $W$ which, such that, for each $\mathbf Q \in \mathcal P$, $(W \cap \bigcap \mathbf Q) \backslash (\bigcup \overline{\mathbf Q}) \not = \emptyset $ (that is, $W$ meets all $V_i$ of $\mathbf Q$ at their intersection, but outside of their intersection with any other $V_j$); but this did not quite work either, because then I'd have to pick the remaining elements in some way and it's possible that different partitions would lead me to the same set. Also, the formula looked ugly as hell, while it seems to me that there should be some relatively simple answer in terms of the cardinalities of the $V_i$ and of their intersections.

What am I missing? It *looks* like I should simply apply the principle of exclusion and exclusion in some way, but the answer still eludes me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make inclusion-exclusion work, and if the answer you get is ugly, well, maybe that's inherent in the problem. Let's start with the observation that the number of subsets that fail to intersect each of the $V_i$ for $i$ in some index set $I\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is $2^{f(I)}$ where $f(I)=\#(U)-\#(\cup_{i\in I}V_i)$. Then the number you want is $$2^{f(\phi)}-\sum_{I:\#(I)=1}2^{f(I)}+\sum_{I:\#(I)=2}2^{f(I)}-\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\#(U)}(-1)^n\sum_{I:\#(I)=n}2^{f(I)}$$ You could factor $2^{\#(U)}$ out from the sum, which would then just involve terms of the form $2^{-\#(\cup_{i\in I}V_i)}$

Comment: Thanks! I really feel dumb now, I don't know why I missed that. I was hoping for something a little more feasible computability-wise, but it seems like summing over all index sets cannot be helped. Time to look at approximations, perhaps...